# Why does shaking our hand result in more copies in dim light than in bright light?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, vision

When we wave our hand really fast, we see several facades of it tagging behind. What causes this? I sense this has something to do with the persistence of vision of our eye similar to what happens in [Newton's disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_disc).

Also when done in dim light, these copies are seen very clearly, but not as much in brighter light. How does the light intensity play a role here?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with this phenomenon, so I tried to reproduce it myself. Whether in bright or dim light, I was only able to see one copy of my hand at a time — no "facades." I am curious if you have any other accounts of people observing this.

Comment: @d_b it does.. and as OP mentioned it becomes clear in dimmer light but not brighter tho..

Comment: What sort of light?  Sunlight, a flame, electric lamp, etc?  If you are using A/C powered artificial light then there may be a strobe effect.

Comment: @badjohn I had bright(white) LED tubelight and and a dim (orange-yellow) LED bulb

Comment: Battery or AC powered?  I have seen the effect that you describe and I always guessed that it was a strobe effect due to the fluctuating power.  The relevance of the brightness is probably related to the persistance of our vision.  There is probably an optimal brightness for the effect.  It might be more of a biology question.

Comment: I just reproduced the effect now by waving my hand in front of the TV.

Comment: @badjohn It was A/C powered

Comment: So, being AC powered, the light is going on and off 100 or 120 times a second (maybe 50 or 60) depending on its design and your power supply.  There is probably some fluorescent element in the bulb so that it dims but not fully go off.  When it is bright, it might remain bright enough for our eyes the whole time and we see a blur.  When it is dim, it might dip below our eyes' sensitivity and the hand is only visible at points in the cycle.

Comment: This does not just happen with A/C power. You can reproduce this in sunlight as well. This has more to do with the human vision system and how the brain interprets it, than about some principle of physics

Comment: @silverrahul I agree that this is probably more biology than physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LEDs are usually powered with some nominal current, and dimmed by applying [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) to the current source output, rather than by continuously varying the current. In such a scenario, maximum brightness is achieved with 100% duty cycle, where no blinking happens at all, while minimum brightness can have a very low duty cycle, like 1%.

This means that a dimly-lit LED will light your hand only 1% of time. Suppose your hand is currently lit. This is the state when you see it first. Then after the lighting is turned off, some time passes while you can't see the hand move further. At the next PWM cycle the hand is lit again, and so on. This makes you see a "dashed" form of the motion blur. Another example would be if a fly or other insect flies by, you'll see it as if there's a train of flies, with the tail fading.

Comment: To test the hypothesis that the effect is due to strobing, one might set up some variable-speed rotor and look for a version of the [stationary helicopter blade effect](https://www.techeblog.com/these-helicopter-blades-appear-to-be-stationary-but-its-actually-just-a-clever-optical-illusion/). I just tried with a cheap box fan, where I can adjust the rotation speed by squeezing the plastic case and adding friction, but I’m not sure it spins fast enough to strobe under my 60Hz lights. Some cheap toys might work. Consider a follow-up question tagged [tag:home-experiment].

Comment: @rob good LED lighting doesn't normally use 60 Hz PWM: it would be worse than incandescent bulbs that flicker at 120 Hz. Cheap LED bulbs do though. But you can try with a mobile phone display — at least all the AMOLED screens I checked, even on flagship Samsung phones, do flicker at something like 50 Hz when at small brightness.

Comment: In my experience, incandescent bulbs generally don’t have enough subsecond temperature variation to flicker at all, but fluorescents with cheap phosphors were famously terrible about causing strobe effects. Of course you’re right that all but the cheapest mains-powered LEDS will have some rectifier to use both halves of the alternating current. But also you can use a rotor with spokes to see the strobe effect at a lower rotor frequency. My other comment got too long to discuss factors of two.